# Idiom: Bear with me

Tags: etymology, idioms, semantics

The sense of this formula is clear. It means be patient with me, be tolerant/lenient. Don't be too harsh on me.

But how can a verb as *"to bear"* develop the meaning of to be tolerant?

*"To bear"* is an old verb with connection to Latin ferre and Greek pherein.
*"To bear"* has split up into several meanings such as *"to carry"*, *"to give birth to a child"*, *"to endure"*, *"to be directed towards"* and similar things which can semantically be understood from the basic meaning to carry or from *Latin* ferre and *Greek* pherein, but no meaning shows a semantic path to *"Bear with me"*.

Comment: "to endure" -- HTH.

Comment: ...meaning both "give birth" (though only English and German strongly retain this sense, and Russian has beremennaya "pregnant") and ***"carry a burden,***  bring" (see infer). (Etymonline)

Comment: "to endure + with me" makes no sense.

Comment: _Bear with_ = ‘endure’. _Bear_ can mean ‘endure’ on its own, too, but in the phrasal verb _bear with_, it always means that. Just like _bear_ on its own can also mean ‘conduct oneself in a certain manner’, while the phrasal verb _bear up_ always has that nuance. The verb itself has lots of different shades of meaning, vaguely connected by an ancestral base meaning. Phrasal verbs made from it just narrow down the meaning, as phrasal verbs tend to do. (As an aside, the Scandinavian equivalent is to _bear over with_ someone, which is just an even more highly specified phrasal verb, really.)

Comment: A farmer, a forest ranger, and a bear cub walked into a bar.  The barman said, "Hey, no unaccompanied minors in here!"  The forest ranger replied, "Bear with me."

Answer (score 5):

From the [Phrase Finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/60/messages/911.html):

> - ***The OED relates "bear with" to "bear" in the sense "sustain [anything painful or trying]; to endure, to tolerate".***

The expression is quite old and can be found in Shakespeare's works:

> - Actually Shakespeare uses the phrase very often, e.g:
> - Julius Caesar: "Bear with me; My heart is in the coffin there with Caesar"
> - Richard III: "My Lord of York will still be cross in talk: Uncle, your grace knows how to bear with him"
> - King Lear: "You must bear with me: Pray you now, forget and forgive"
> - and As You Like it, in which he puns on it. Celia says: "I pray you, bear with me, I cannot go no further." Touchstone replies: "For my part, I had rather bear with [put up with] you than bear [carry] you."
>
>   - Shakespeare certainly didn't invent it; it was clearly a standard part of Elizabethan speech. (It's quite possible, though, that it was the frequent occurrence of it in his plays that kept it familiar and current, and that otherwise it might simply have fallen out of use.)

Comment: You should provide a link, this extract looks like several people are giving their own personal imput

Comment: Is this just a cut and paste from that link? It seems like the only relevant part is the last bullet point. Can you restrict to that and add something yourself that attempts to explain why 'bear' and 'tolerate' are semantically related?

Comment: +1 for **The OED relates "bear with" to "bear" in the sense "sustain [anything painful or trying]; to endure, to tolerate".**

Comment: MacMillan shows that in BrE this formula is used for "Please wait a moment, I'll be  ready for you in a few minutes". http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/bear-with

Comment: Yes, the idea is to bear patience ( like a weight ) out of courtesy. http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bear+with

Answer (score 0):

My personal impression is that the expression bear (meaning to carry/to endure or whatever) + with me is insufficiently explained. Even OED is elegantly wiping away the problem that the additional with me has no logic by not mentioning it at all.
If a secreatary says to a visitor please bear with me for a moment I'll be ready for you in a few minutes
we may interpret "bear" as "Please bear/endure the unpleasant waiting". But why should the visitor bear this unpleasantness with the secretary. She has nothing to bear/endure.

So the idea I have is that the expression was originally a two-verb expression such as

Bear (the unpleasantness of waiting) and put up with it or and put up with me (finishing this work here).

Something of this kind where "with me" really has a logic. Of course, such a hypothesis can't be proved. But if we have no convincing explanation for a historically dark expression I think a hypothesis that makes the expression plausible is better than explanations that wipe away inconsistencies.

Answer (score 0):

I always understood this in the literal, etymologic sense from *to bear*, PIE *bher(H)- "to carry", thus in my mind translating to German *ertragen* "to endure, suffer, sustain; to yield" (as a burden is carried , lifted, etc; as a tree bears fruit, carrying fruit so to speak, some overlap with *bear* "to birth, bring forth"), apparently from *tragen* "to carry" (cp. *to drag*).

If Latin *fero* bears the same connotation, "endure". Common census has it reconstructing the same root (with *bh > *f*). Which is however slightly suspect. For one,  *fero* is "*A suppletive paradigm consisting of two different roots. The present stem is from Proto-Italic *ferō, from Proto-Indo-European *bʰéreti (“to bear, carry”), from the root *bʰer-. ... The perfect stem, originally of* tollō, *is from Proto-Italic *tetolai, from Proto-Indo-European *tetólh₂e (“to be holding up”), from the root *telh₂-. The stem of* lātus *has the same root, reduced from Proto-Italic *tlātos, from Proto-Indo-European *tl̥h₂tós. It is cognate with English thole (“to endure”).*" But suppletive paradigms should be considered highly suspect. First, there is *per- etc. whence Latin *pro, per*, English *fare*, Ger. *fahren* "drive", *ausführen* "export", and much more; as a traveling word, the Germanic stems relating to the semantic field of trade might have influenced Latin, or vice versa. The same goes for Greek *phero* "to bring", of course. Another problem is that *bher- is rather polysemous reconstruction--meaning, the stem was highly productive, and there is no telling whether "carry" should be the sense that begot all of them. In that sense, German *ertragen* might be a loan translation, that cannot inform the sought etymology. Yet, Latin *f* frequently reflects PIE *dh (e.g. *facio*, En. *do*, PIE *dheH-) instead, and *tragen* does reflect
*dʰregʰ- "to run"(?) indeed, so far without a Latin reflex; the -g suffix is perhaps secondary (cp. Greek *dromos* "run") as much as the onset a zero grade, corresponding to a full grade, that could reasonably yield *fero*, i.e. [*dher-](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/d%CA%B0er-), with "Indo-Iranian *dʰar- (“hold, stop, bear, carry, receive, hold up right”)" and several Latin descendants, indeed Italic *dher-o- > Latin *f-*, though not *fero* (see there). Meanwhile, I have no clue about Celtic, except that some branches affricated some plosives.

This means the state of Proto-Indo-European as presented in wiktionary and the sources that they follow is a mess, and not of much help here. Whether that's a dialectal division in PIE or later--or if *r-gh- is actually the significant part of these roots (cf. e.g. *reach*, Ger. *reichen* "to extend, suffice", perhaps "grasp"), with *bhe- and *dhe- mere suffixes (cp. Ger. *bei-bringen* with n-infix, or *bereichern*)--is mere speculation at this point.

Another *problem* with relevance to the question, in my humble opinion, is *burden*, Ger. *Bürde*. Also compare idiom. *jemandem einen Bären aufbinden* (to burden someone with something, to deceive, literally to bind a bear (the animal) on somebody's back) and *einen Bärendienst erweisen* (to do someone a huge favour, literally to do someone a bear service (huge as the animal?)). In this light, the incongruency in the referenced wikipages linking from *dher- to Lat. *feros*, where a different etymology--or a different lexem all together--reads instead: "*From earlier *xweros, from Proto-Indo-European *ǵʰwér-os, from *ǵʰwer- (“wild animal”). Adjective *feros 1. wild, savage*"; seems notable insofar *bear* as a wild animal, as much as a taboo word, may be comparable; even *ursus* "bear" may have become conflated (not to be confused with *Gyros*, Ger. *Dreh-Spieß*). Further, *ghw-, the aspirated labial velar is thought to derive Germanic *w, cf. *warm* (uncertain), and analoguous to Kurdish, I'd see *schwer* here, too, instead of *(s)wer- "sever", or at least *schwül*. It might be a stretch of the imagination to compare thus *to bear with* and *warten* "to wait". Don't bear with me.

On another note, above mentioned *telh₂- reminds of *tolerate*. Similarly "The stem of* lātus" is reminiscent of *leniency*. It seems clear that there's a connection. Only the preposition *with* still strikes me as odd. I'd suggest it implies exchange, *negotiate with me*, or indeed Ger. *Unterhalte (dich) mit mir* (let's have a talk, entertain with me; *halt* "hold" glosses Italic *dher-o; *Unterhalt* means "sustainance, livelyhood; care for" rather than *entertainment*, with *teno* anyway "to hold, grab, understand", *tendo* "to take care of")

Answer (score -1):

I believe it may have Catholic origins as in the stations of the cross Jesus literally asked for help to bare the cross. Consider also the relevant idiom "my cross to bear/bare". So many languages have been shaped by Catholic tradition it would be weird if there was any other explanation. Consider "bear with me" means that the speaker is revealing something to the audience personal about what the speaker is doing - such as bearing or even wearing the cross as for centuries Christians had to exist in secret to avoid persecution (ironic). I'm hardly a religious scholar so take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

The following answer is not based on etymology but on my though of why people are using *"Bear with me"* with this meaning.

---

A bear in the common imagination is associated to teddy bear.

Which is sweet.

So : *"bear with me"* = *"be sweet with me"* = *"be kind with me"*.

Comment: You find this remark about bear , the animal, everywhere on the internet. But the animal has really nothing to do with the verb to bear.  But your association is not so bad - unfortunately it is not etymology and semantic shift.

Comment: @rogermue I don't say the verb has something to do with, just that people use it for this reason, which is your question.

Comment: Good, Yohann. It is also interesting what kind of associations speakers who use this formula have in mind. This is quite a new and really interesting aspect of my question. Originally I was interested only in the etymology, but I should consider this new aspect, too. However  it is not so easy to get  to associations people have with dark expressions.

Comment: @rogermue I never used this expression, but it is the first thing that came to my mind when I read it. And I bet I am not the only one ;)

Comment: Good Yohann. I would be glad if more people told us their associations. On another forum one poster, a woman, told me she connects the formula with child-bearing  and mid-wifery.

Comment: 1+ for stating clearly that you are giving your personal association, not an attempt at an etymological explanation.